# How can I test react toggle with jest+Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hi Recently I'm testing my react application with jest+enzyme,
and it makes me really confused to write a test with useState or useEffect..

so this is my code and I want to test when user click the button, description is shows or not.(by change state value)

```
const Job = ({ job }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = (id) => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
    <Card>
    
        <Card.Text>
          <Button id="button" onClick={toggle} variant="primary">
            {!isOpen ? "View Detail" : "Hide Detail"}
          </Button>
        </Card.Text>
        {isOpen && (
          <div className="mt-4">
            <ReactMardown source={job.description} />
          </div>
        )}
    
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Job;
```

Job.test.js

```
import React from "react";

import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { mount, shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import Job from "./Job";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("when user click the button state value should changed", () => {
  const job = jest.fn();

  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Job job={job} />);
  });
  it("should render", () => {
    expect(wrapper).not.toBeNull();
  });

  test("user click button", () => {
    const setIsOpen = jest.fn();
    wrapper.find("#button").at(1).simulate("click");
    expect(setIsOpen).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({ isOpen: false });
  });
});
```

but it only passed the first test..

Comment: Should `expect(setIsOpen).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({ isOpen: false });` not compare to true, as on click the value reverts? Also I'm not sure about the jest API, but you provide `setIsOpen` a boolean, but check for an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally better, especially in stateless components, not to test the implementation, but its result.

```
it('user click button', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(ReactMardown)).toHaveLength(0);

    wrapper.find('#button').simulate('click');

    expect(wrapper.find(ReactMardown)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: How can I test a DarkMode button that toggles state 'light' and 'dark'?

Comment: @nambk I've added an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

@nambk I'd go with testing the style, eg. some component's `background-color`:

```
expect(component.find('#item-id').prop('style')).toHaveProperty('backgroundColor' 'black');
```

Comment: In `header` component, I have `const [theme, toggleTheme] = useDarkMode();` 
and using `<ThemeProvider theme={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>`.
The state will be 'light' or 'dark' when using ThemeProvider from styled-components. So what is the best way to write a test for this case?

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest reading about testing the React hooks.